# .readLine() not getting any value giving result as null

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The reader.readLine() is returning NULL.

I am trying to send the value from my android to PHP and then get back the result and display it but stuck due to this error.
The database just has name and password. Getting all usernames with the same password.
Thanks in advance.

#### Java Code:

```
package com.example.my;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    String id;
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = null;
    String line = null;
    String name = null;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        final EditText et_p = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPSWD);
        Button b_go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGO);
        System.out.println("YO");
        b_go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                id = et_p.getText().toString();
                go();
            }
        });
    }

    public void go() {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> pair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.2.5/login.php");
            pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pair));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            System.out.println("ERROR IS" + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        try {
            int count = 0;
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "ISO-8859-1"), 8);
            System.out.println("READERTOSTRING" + reader.toString());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println("RANDOM");
            /*
             *
             * ERROR AFTER THIS
             *
             */
            line = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println("VALUE OF LINE:"+line);
            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                System.out.println("ROUND" + count + "--" + sb.toString());
                count++;
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            System.out.println("RESULT IS " + result);
            Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
        }
        try {
            System.out.println("HERE0" + result);
            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            System.out.println("HERE1");
            name = (json_data.getString("success"));
            System.out.println("HERE1");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Name : " + name,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

#### THE XML CODE IS:-

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","sen","test1");
    if(mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
    echo "Failed to connect ".mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $name=$_GET['name'];
    $password=$_GET['password'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name FROM users where name='$name' and password='$password'");
    
    //$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name FROM users");
    
    while($arr = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
       if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    
    $product=array();
    $product["name"]=$arr["arr"];
    $product["password"]=$arr["password"];
    $response["success"]=1;
    $response["get"]=array();
    array_push($response["get"],$product);
    //IF NOT TRY $output[]=$arr;
    echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else
    {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    }
    //print(json_encode($product));
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

ERROR

```
04-21 13:10:44.332: I/System.out(1339): READERTOSTRINGjava.io.BufferedReader@5275e610 
04-21 13:10:44.332: I/System.out(1339): RANDOM 
04-21 13:10:44.336: I/System.out(1339): VALUE OF LINE:null 
04-21 13:10:44.336: I/System.out(1339): RESULT IS 
04-21 13:10:44.336: E/pass 2(1339): connection success 
04-21 13:10:44.340: I/System.out(1339): HERE0 
04-21 13:10:44.344: E/Fail 3(1339): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Comment: where is the error message

Comment: first of all separate the network handler inside a AsyncTask or thread. then show logcat

Comment: 04-21 13:10:44.332: I/System.out(1339): READERTOSTRINGjava.io.BufferedReader@5275e610
04-21 13:10:44.332: I/System.out(1339): RANDOM
04-21 13:10:44.336: I/System.out(1339): VALUE OF LINE:null
04-21 13:10:44.336: I/System.out(1339): RESULT IS 
04-21 13:10:44.336: E/pass 2(1339): connection success 
04-21 13:10:44.340: I/System.out(1339): HERE0
04-21 13:10:44.344: E/Fail 3(1339): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Comment: I read that i can use -StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); instead of a AsyncTask or thread is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like maybe your PHP code is not returning any value at all. I'm not sure if this matters, but shouldn't you be using `mysqli_num_rows()` instead of `mysql_num_rows()`?

EDIT: `$password=$_GET['password'];` According to your error, there is no 'password' value sent in your request. Check for a typo, and make sure a value is actually being sent for the password.

EDIT 2: You're using post in your Android code (`HttpPost`), but get in PHP (`$_GET`). Change your $_GET to $_REQUEST or $_POST instead.

EDIT 3:

1. Add password to your select. You are trying to access it from your result array without having selected it in SQL.
2. `$product["name"]=$arr["arr"];` should be `$product["name"]=$arr["name"];`

EDIT 4:
Move this: `$response["get"]=array();` before the while loop, and move this: `echo json_encode($response);` (both of them) after the while loop. Then you should have a JSON structure like this:

```
{
   "success":1,
   "post":[
      {"name":"Abc","password":null},
      {‌​"name":"Def","password":null},
      {"name":"Ghi","password":null‌​},
      {"name":"Jkl","password":null},
      {"na‌​me":"Mno","password":null}
   ]
}
```

As you can see your results are in a JSONArray (signified by the [ ] tags) called "post". So something like this:

```
JSONArray results = json_data.getJSONObject("post");
for (int i = 0; i < results .size(); i++) {
    JSONObject item = results.getJSONObject(i); 
    String name = item.getString("name");
}
```

Comment: Do you have error reporting on in PHP? If not put error_reporting(E_ALL); above your code to see if you get a response of some kind.

Comment: Am getting this Is this an error or just a warning? :-  Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\login.php on line 7 Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\login.php on line 8

Comment: Did this in the java code :- HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.173.1/login.php");
   pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", id));
   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pair));
   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
   is = entity.getContent();

Comment: And this in php code :-//$name=$_GET['name'];
$password=$_GET['password'];
//$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name FROM users where name='$name' and password='$password'");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name FROM users where password='$password'");                                                   Still getting the same Error

Comment: This error was solved but all values are coming as NULL:-04-21 15:00:02.598: I/System.out(1486): HERE0{"success":1,"get":[{"name":null,"password":null}]}{"success":1,"get":[{"name":null,"password":null}]}{"success":1,"get":[{"name":null,"password":null}]}{"success":1,"get":[{"name":null,"password":null}]}{"success":1,"get":[{"name":null,"password":null}]}
04-21 15:00:02.598: I/System.out(1486): HERE1
04-21 15:00:02.602: I/System.out(1486): HERE1
Can you Please Help on this now

Comment: The database has values and shows the value in database:test1 Table:users when i write select * from users where password=123; in MYSQL command line Client

Comment: name = (json_data.getString("name"));                            this line is giving an error stating :- 04-21 15:19:35.062: E/Fail 3(1723): org.json.JSONException: No value for name                   
but before that i am getting this:- 04-21 15:19:35.058: I/System.out(1723): HERE0{"success":1,"post":[{"name":"Abc","password":null}]}{"success":1,"post":[{"name":"Def","password":null}]}{"success":1,"post":[{"name":"Ghi","password":null}]}{"success":1,"post":[{"name":"Jkl","password":null}]}{"success":1,"post":[{"name":"Mno","password":null}]}
 So how do i access the name if not like that.

Comment: Alright, posted my final edit. You should really consider practicing your debugging skills. Always look for typos in your code and make sure to print everything out to see what's hapening.